# Google map limites API

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I have 80 Phone and i am listening their location on the map. I am seeing in the map their location. I am setupping marker map location about 2 sec . When i am going to listen their coordinates , i am changing the marker values from api. 
I have 80 phone i am listening them 7/24 so i need (80x24x60x30 = 3.456.000) API Request. But i can just 25.000 free request how can i do it ? Do have any way ? OR how much cash i give google for it ? I am using this function every 2 second

```
Marker.setPosition(latlng);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a cost associated with using the API, if you exceed 2,500 requests per day.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/usage-limits

Comment: I want to watch the people on the map. And i need 3b API REQUEST :/